# Как добавить в массив перед отрицательным числом такое же положительное

Tags: swift, xcode

Подскажите, есть массив целых чисел, в нем есть отрицательные числа. Как перед отрицательными числами в массив добавить такие же положительные? Пример ниже

```
var arrayInt: [Int] = [10, -15, 20, -200]
```

//result

```
[10, 15, -15, 20, 200, -200]
```

Comment: Мм... А какие трудности в осуществлении этого дела встретились? Цикл, if, abs

Comment: Я не изучал еще abs, знаю как добавлять элементы в массив, получать индекс и значения элементов, но как добавить именно перед отрицательным не знаю

Comment: В данном случае, когда известно после if , что число отрицательное, вместо abs можно сделать x = -x; Напишите код обхода,  проверки и добавления в массив, вставьте в вопрос, дальше подправим

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Comment: Как вставить в массив именно перед отрицательными числами?

Answer (score 1):

Можно решить данную задачу как минимум двумя способами

- с использованием второго массива
- с модификацией исходного массива

```
// variant 1

var arrayInt: [Int] = [10, -15, 20, -200]
var arrayIntResult = [Int]()

for item in arrayInt {
    if item < 0 {
        arrayIntResult.append(-item)
    }
    
    arrayIntResult.append(item)
}

arrayInt = arrayIntResult

print(arrayInt)

assert(arrayInt == [10, 15, -15, 20, 200, -200])

// variant 2

arrayInt = [10, -15, 20, -200]

var position = 0

for item in arrayInt {
    if item < 0 {
        arrayInt.insert(-item, at: position)
        position += 1
    }
    
    position += 1
}

print(arrayInt)

assert(arrayInt == [10, 15, -15, 20, 200, -200])
```